# Unable to convert UTF-16 encoded .CSV to UTF-8 in Shiny (R)

Tags: r, csv, shiny, utf-8, utf-16le

I have been having trouble converting a UTF-16LE encoded .CSV file into UTF-8. I know that I can manually re-save the file into the desired encoding, but I want this functionality to be built into the Shiny app as my user base is not that tech savvy to even correctly save into the right file formats. This is the file they have to work with and so it is the file I have to work with too.

Ultimately, I would like to save the csv file as a data.frame() so that I can have the server wrangle the data a little bit (e.g., arranging, reshaping, etc.) before outputting a download file. I have tried the iconv() function, as well as, converting it into a JSON file with jsonlite and then converting the json into a UTF-8 encoded file.

*For reproducibility*

Here is a download link to the csv file I am testing with: https://www.mediafire.com/file/w4iahngpa8skgmp/InputFile.csv/file

Here is my Shiny script:

```
library(DT)
library(rio)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "blue",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Import", tabName = "Import",  icon = icon("file-upload")),
      menuItem("Convert", tabName = "Convert", icon = icon("recycle"))
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
      '.myClass { 
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: "Bookman Old Style",Bookman Old Style,Arial,sans-serif;
        padding: 0 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: white;
      }
    '))),
    tags$script(HTML('
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("header").find("nav").append(\'<span class="myClass"> Here is my dashboard </span>\');
      })
     ')),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Import",
              h2("Import CSV File", align = "center"),
              fileInput("file", "Choose CSV File",multiple = FALSE, accept = NULL,
                        width = NULL, buttonLabel = "Browse...",
                        placeholder = "No file selected"),
              actionButton("preview", "Preview Current Data Set"),
              fluidRow(
                mainPanel(
                  dataTableOutput("impOut")
                )
              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Convert",
              h2("Convert CSV File", align = "center"),
              actionButton("convert", "Convert!"),
              actionButton("preview2", "Preview Converted Data Set"),
              fluidRow(
                mainPanel(
                  dataTableOutput("conOut")
                )
              )
              
      )
    )
  ))

server <- function(input,output,server) {
  
  observeEvent(
    input$preview, 
    {
      data <- read.csv(input$file$datapath, fileEncoding = "UTF-16", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
      output$impOut <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(data)
      })
    })
  observeEvent(
    input$convert, 
    {
      rawDat <- read.csv(input$file$datapath, fileEncoding = "UTF-16", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
      fileDat <- iconv(rawDat, from = "UTF-16", to = "UTF-8")
      output$conOut <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(fileDat)
      })
    })
}  
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinydashboard_0.7.2 rio_0.5.29           DT_0.22              shiny_1.7.1         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_2.2.0         Rcpp_1.0.8.3      jquerylib_0.1.4   bslib_0.3.1       cellranger_1.1.0  compiler_4.1.3    pillar_1.7.0     
 [8] later_1.3.0       forcats_0.5.1     tools_4.1.3       digest_0.6.29     jsonlite_1.8.0    lifecycle_1.0.1   tibble_3.1.6     
[15] pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_1.0.2       openxlsx_4.2.5    cli_3.2.0         crosstalk_1.2.0   yaml_2.3.5        curl_4.3.2       
[22] haven_2.4.3       fastmap_1.1.0     withr_2.5.0       sass_0.4.1        vctrs_0.4.0       htmlwidgets_1.5.4 hms_1.1.1        
[29] fontawesome_0.2.2 glue_1.6.2        data.table_1.14.2 R6_2.5.1          fansi_1.0.3       readxl_1.4.0      foreign_0.8-82   
[36] magrittr_2.0.2    promises_1.2.0.1  ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.2   mime_0.12         xtable_1.8-4      httpuv_1.6.5     
[43] utf8_1.2.2        stringi_1.7.6     cachem_1.0.6      crayon_1.5.1
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Does the code you wrote not work? Do you get an error or something? What problem do you have using the data in it's current form?

Comment: The code I wrote to import the csv file into a dataframe does not work. If I it is not recognized as a dataframe, I can't wrangle it.

Comment: Since you are on Windows are your sure you caught the right encoding there and that it's not "Windows-1252"? I also have good experience with these two funcs `enc2native` and `enc2utf8` when fighting with ecnodings